# How to avoid keyboard flickering when opening AlertDialog with EditText while another EditText is already focused?

Tags: android, dialog, focus, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to open an AlertDialog containing an EditText field. I want the EditText in the AlertDialog to automatically receive focus and show soft keyboard when the dialog opens. I achieve it this way:

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(d -> {
    dialogInput.requestFocus();
});
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

However, if the soft keyboard is already active when I trigger the dialog, it closes and then reopens quickly, resulting in a jarring animation:
[Demonstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtSXQ.gif)

How can I prevent this behaviour, and ensure that soft keyboard stays open throughout the AlertDialog opening transition?

Full code to reproduce:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void noOp(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout contentView = new FrameLayout(this);
        setContentView(contentView);

        EditText bottomInput = new EditText(this);
        bottomInput.setHint("Bottom input");
        contentView.addView(bottomInput, new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM));

        Button openDialogButton = new Button(this);
        contentView.addView(openDialogButton, new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
        openDialogButton.setText("Open dialog");
        openDialogButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            EditText dialogInput = new EditText(this);
            dialogInput.setHint("Dialog input");
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage("Message")
                    .setView(dialogInput)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", this::noOp)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", this::noOp)
                    .create();
            dialog.setOnShowListener(d -> {
                dialogInput.requestFocus();
            });
            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
            dialog.show();
        });
    }
}
```